# Foreach loop Null model in Razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm trying to Add values in table(Flight) which have one to many relation with table(Flight classes)
for view of `flightClasses`  i'm using foreach loop but it comes with null model 
i can't understand how to do it please help me

Flight Table will have one Row against which i want to add multiple rows in the FlightClasses Table
Flight Modle

```
public class FlightModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FlightName { get; set; }
        public string FlightNo { get; set; }
        public string OriginCity { get; set; }
        public string DestinationCity { get; set; }
        public DateTime Departure { get; set; }
        public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FlightClassesModel> FlightClasses { get; set; }
    }
```

FlightClasses Model

```
public class FlightClassesModel
    {

        public int FlightClassesModelId { get; set; }
        public type Class { get; set; }
        public int AvailableSeats { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public virtual FlightModel Flight { get; set; }

        public int? FlightId { get; set; }
    }
    public enum type
    {
        Business_Class,
        First_Class,
        Club_Class
    }
```

View

```
@model Airline.Models.FlightModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>FlightModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FlightName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FlightName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FlightName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FlightNo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FlightNo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FlightNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OriginCity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="OriginCity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="OriginCity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DestinationCity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DestinationCity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DestinationCity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Departure" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Departure" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Departure" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Arrival" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Arrival" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Arrival" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @foreach (var flightClass in Model.FlightClasses)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@flightClass.Class" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="@flightClass.Class" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<type>()"></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="@flightClass.Class" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@flightClass.AvailableSeats" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@flightClass.AvailableSeats" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@flightClass.AvailableSeats" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@flightClass.Price" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@flightClass.Price" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@flightClass.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            }

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(FlightModel flightModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(flightModel);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(flightModel);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your `HttpGet` as well? are you assigning some initial values befoer create? looks like something is wrong in the create logic! you are creating a new `FlightModel` that has one-to-many relation with `FlightClasses` and trying to loop through `FlightClasses` that could be null if no values have been assigned during `Get`

Comment: i'm passing nothing in HttpGet  i have given that above the HttpPost methode

Comment: So you can't do `foreach` loop for the `FlightModel.FlightClasses` because it is null by default. You have to assign initial values during `Get` or just create related `FlightClasses` in a different view.

Comment: how i'm suppose to do that
i'm actually new in asp.net core and don't know much about it
can you guide me

Comment: First just create the `FlightModel` without `FlightClasses`. Then you can create a new page for creating related `FlightClasses`, pass the relevant `FlightModel.Id` to the create view and assign it to the `FlightClass.FlightId` property

Comment: Essential information if you ever want to change the order, add, or remove items from the list: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: Thank you sir for your help